# Is computed property always be used for retrieving store values in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

One of my Vuex store saves application configurations which get set once and never gets updated. As I've seen so far, we use computed properties to retrieve any store value. The main reason is to re-evaluate the result when the value in the store changes. But as the value of my store is not going to change, then should I directly call the store value or should I use with computed properties only?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If by computed you mean store Getters then no, you don't always have to use Getters to read store state..  You can read store state directly.  Just don't mutate what you read. I avoid using store getters unless i specifically need to calculate and cache something.

Comment: But is there any performance difference between storing state in cache vs in mutable data property?

Comment: sure, it's more operations.  Besides performance, I've had several cases where the Getter is not updated immediately like direct state is.